# iOS : how can i edit table view by mouse click and keyboard?

Tags: ios, tableview, edit

I have a table view in my profileViewController that display user's data such : first name, last name , birthday , gender...
I want to edit this table view by clicking in my custom edit button and i can after edit it by mouse and keyboard in ever selected row. 
I have implemented a method :

```
-(IBAction)editTableView:(UIButton *)sender {
    if ( sender == self.editButton) {
        NSLog(@"Editing");

        [super setEditing:TRUE];
        [self.userTableView setEditing:TRUE];
        self.editing = YES;
    }
}
```

I have searched on the net but I find that edit table view means add or delete a row in this table view and my purpose is to can edit ever row selected by keyboard and mouse ...

Comment: How are you using a mouse on an iOS device?

Comment: @rmaddy you are right but  what i mean when i test in my simulator iOS ...
In iOS device , it will be touching and keyboard ..

Comment: So you want text to be editable. Do you know what a UITextField is?

Comment: @matt  not only text , I want also to selected gender by clicking or touching the appropriate image (male or female ) ..

Comment: Well then you'll need some other interface too. What I'm saying is simply this: What the user can do in your table view cell depends on what's _in_ your table view cell. Work out the desired interface for just a normal world with no table; then you can start to solve it for a table view cell.

Comment: Is it just me or the OP wants to be able to use their hardware keyboard and mouse on their Mac, to use their app?

Comment: @n00bProgrammer can you explain more . i don't fathom you very well.

Answer (score 0):

A typical interface is this: The user taps on a cell, and you *present* a presented view controller where the user can edit the same data that appears in that cell. For example, if the cell contains a `name` label, the presented view controller contains a `name` text field. If the cell contains a `gender` label, the presented view controller contains a `gender` segmented control. The user edits, and then taps Cancel or Done. You dismiss the presented view controller. If the user tapped Done, you also save the user's changes into your data model and reload the data into the table.

Comment: A case in point is Apple's Calendar app. When you tap on an event, you see a display of that event that is _not_ editable. But there's an Edit button. When you tap that, you get a presented view controller whose view shows a _different_ display of the event, one that _is_ editable, along with a Cancel button and a Done button. I'm suggesting that tapping a cell, or an Edit button within the cell, should do something like that.